# How to find the common members between different vectors by a majority voting rule

Tags: r

I am trying to find the common elements between multiple vectors. The current situation is a little tricky, where the common elements do not need to be the totally same, but could have some errors, say +/- 1, even the common elements do not need to show in all of these vectors, which are chosen by a majority voting rule. Besides, these vectors have different lengths. Here is an example,

```
a <- c(5,7,11,18,27,30);

b <- c(5,8,18,26);

c <- c(6,7,10,26,30)
```

5 in a, 5 in b, 6 in c, will be regarded as a common element, which will be taken the floor(the average), i.e. 5;

7 in a, 8 in b, 7 in c, will be regarded as a common element, which will be taken the floor(the average), i.e. 7;

11 in a, 10 in c, will be regarded as a common element, which will be taken the floor(the average), i.e. 10;

The same rules apply to 18,26,30

Therefore, the final result that I should get is ***c(5,7,10,18,26,30)***

Comment: Hi mym, welcome to Stack Overflow. I fear that your algorithm is too complex for anyone to implement effectively with the information you have provided. You should provide additional context to the problem. Otherwise, someone will come by and write an answer that exactly reproduces your requested result but will be totally useless for your actual problem. See the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/730130) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a moving window approach. First we can combine the values into a single vector, and then we use a moving window of size 'majority' (in this case, 2). If the values in the moving window are within the error range (in this case, 1), add the lowest value to our list of common values, then remove those values. Then continue checking the values.

Here it is as a function:

```
#vec_list -> list of the vectors to compare
#error -> margin of error to tolerate
#returns a vector of the common numbers
get_common_values = function(vec_list, error){
  all = sort(unlist(vec_list)) #put all the numbers in one vector and sort them
  majority = ceiling(length(vec_list)/2) #get the number of values that constitute a majority
  
  common = c() #initialize an empty vector to store the values
  #now we'll loop over 'all' and find common values - and we'll remove them as we go
  #this is basically a moving window approach
  while(length(all) >= majority){ #keep going until we've gone through all the elements
    vals_i = all[1:majority] #get the values at the front
    if(diff(range(vals_i)) <= error){ #if the range is <= to the error, then this value can be considered one of the 'common' values
      new_val = min(vals_i) #get the minimum of the values
      common = c(common, new_val) #add it to our vector of common values
      all = all[!(all %in% new_val:(new_val+error))] #remove any of the values that fall within this range 
    } else {
      all = all[2:length(all)] #if the range isn't greater than the error, just remove the first element
    }
  }
  return(common)
}
```

We can use it like this:

```
a = c(5,7,11,18,27,30)
b = c(5,8,18,26)
c = c(6,7,10,26,30)
get_common_values(list(a,b,c),1)
```

This returns `5  7 10 18 26 30`.

It also works with more than three vectors, and with different error tolerances:

```
set.seed(0)
a = sample(1:100,8)
b = sample(1:100,10)
c = sample(1:100,7)
d = sample(1:100,11)
e = sample(1:100,9)
get_common_values(list(a,b,c,d,e),2)
```

Note that this assumes that there are no duplicates within each vector, which seems to be a valid assumption based on the info you've provided.

Comment: Hi dfriend21, thank you very much for your help. I'm sorry that I didn't make it clear. In my example, 6 should not occur. Since we have found two 5 in a and b, we will take 6 in c as the same member as these two 5. After doing this, 6 in c should not be checked again.

Comment: I modified my answer (substantially!) I think the new code should do what you want.